# ValueError: pic should be 2/3 dimensional. Got 4 dimensions

Tags: deep-learning, pytorch, computer-vision, data-augmentation, image-augmentation

I am trying to implement an augmentation function to my images and masks, I have defined the augmentations like below:

```
if config.AUG == "PRIMEAugmentation":
    augmentations = [autocontrast, equalize, posterize, rotate, solarize, shear_x, shear_y, translate_x, translate_y]
```

and the function is like below:

```
import torch
from torch.distributions import Dirichlet, Beta

class PRIMEAugmentation:
    def __init__(self, mixture_width=3, mixture_depth=-1):
        self.mixture_width = mixture_width
        self.mixture_depth = mixture_depth

    def __call__(self, x, mask):
        x = torch.from_numpy(x).to(torch.float32)
        mask = torch.from_numpy(mask)
        ws = Dirichlet(torch.ones(self.mixture_width)).sample((x.shape[0],))
        m = Beta(torch.ones(1), torch.ones(1)).sample().expand(x.shape[0], 1, 1, 1)

        x_aug = torch.zeros_like(x).to(torch.float32)
        mask_aug = torch.zeros_like(mask).to(torch.float32)
        for i in range(self.mixture_width):
            x_i = x.clone()
            mask_i = mask.clone()
            for d in range(self.mixture_depth):
                op = torch.randint(len(self.augmentations), size=(x.shape[0],)).tolist()
                x_i, mask_i = self.augmentations[op](x_i, mask_i)
            print("ws[:, i] shape:", ws[:, i].shape)
            print("x_i shape:", x_i.shape)
            print("mask_i shape:", mask_i.shape)
            x_aug += ws[:, i][:, None, None] * x_i.to(torch.float32)
            mask_aug += ws[:, i][:, None] * mask_i.to(torch.float32)

        mixed = (1 - m) * x + m * x_aug.sum(dim=1)
        mixed_mask = (1 - m) * mask + m * mask_aug.sum(dim=1)
        return mixed.numpy().astype(np.uint8), mixed_mask.numpy().astype(np.uint8)
```

and I have called it like the following way:

```
augmenter_PRIMEAugmentation = aug_lib_new.PRIMEAugmentation()

import os

def image_mask_transformation(image,mask,img_trans,aug_trans=False):
    transformed = img_trans(image=image, mask=mask)
    image = transformed["image"]
    mask = transformed["mask"]

    if aug_trans in augmenter_list:
        image,mask = eval('augmenter_'+aug_trans)(image, mask)
```

but I am getting an error:

```
    raise ValueError('pic should be 2/3 dimensional. Got {} dimensions.'.format(pic.ndim))
ValueError: pic should be 2/3 dimensional. Got 4 dimensions.
```

full error trace:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/home/Crack-PRIME4/main.py", line 422, in <module>
    train_logs = train_step(model, optimizer, criteria, trainLoader, accumulation_steps, scaler, epoch, epochs)
  File "/home/Crack-PRIME4/main.py", line 240, in train_step
    for idx, data in enumerate(bar):
  File "/home/anaconda3/envs/myenv/lib/python3.9/site-packages/tqdm/std.py", line 1182, in __iter__
    for obj in iterable:
  File "/home//anaconda3/envs/myenv/lib/python3.9/site-packages/torch/utils/data/dataloader.py", line 630, in __next__
    data = self._next_data()
  File "/home/anaconda3/envs/myenv/lib/python3.9/site-packages/torch/utils/data/dataloader.py", line 1345, in _next_data
    return self._process_data(data)
  File "/home/anaconda3/envs/myenv/lib/python3.9/site-packages/torch/utils/data/dataloader.py", line 1371, in _process_data
    data.reraise()
  File "/home/anaconda3/envs/myenv/lib/python3.9/site-packages/torch/_utils.py", line 694, in reraise
    raise exception
ValueError: Caught ValueError in DataLoader worker process 0.
Original Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/home/anaconda3/envs/myenv/lib/python3.9/site-packages/torch/utils/data/_utils/worker.py", line 308, in _worker_loop
    data = fetcher.fetch(index)
  File "/home/anaconda3/envs/myenv/lib/python3.9/site-packages/torch/utils/data/_utils/fetch.py", line 51, in fetch
    data = [self.dataset[idx] for idx in possibly_batched_index]
  File "/home/anaconda3/envs/myenv/lib/python3.9/site-packages/torch/utils/data/_utils/fetch.py", line 51, in <listcomp>
    data = [self.dataset[idx] for idx in possibly_batched_index]
  File "/home/Crack-PRIME4/tool/dataset.py", line 215, in __getitem__
    image_store, mask_store = image_mask_transformation(image, mask, self.img_trans, self.aug_trans)
  File "/home/Crack-PRIME4/tool/dataset.py", line 188, in image_mask_transformation
    final_image = transforms.ToTensor()(image)
  File "/home/anaconda3/envs/myenv/lib/python3.9/site-packages/torchvision/transforms/transforms.py", line 97, in __call__
    return F.to_tensor(pic)
  File "/home/anaconda3/envs/myenv/lib/python3.9/site-packages/torchvision/transforms/functional.py", line 105, in to_tensor
    raise ValueError('pic should be 2/3 dimensional. Got {} dimensions.'.format(pic.ndim))
ValueError: pic should be 2/3 dimensional. Got 4 dimensions.
```

image-mask transformation is called from:

```
class SegmentationDataset(Dataset):
    def __init__(self, imagePaths, maskPaths, img_trans, aug_trans = False, baug = 1):
        self.imagePaths = imagePaths
        self.maskPaths = maskPaths
        self.img_trans = img_trans
        self.aug_trans = aug_trans
        self.baug = baug

    def __len__(self):
        # Number of images
        return len(self.imagePaths)

    def __getitem__(self, idx):
        imagePath = self.imagePaths[idx]

        image = cv2.imread(imagePath)
        # OpenCV loads an image in the BGR format,
        # which we convert to the RGB format
        image = cv2.cvtColor(image, cv2.COLOR_BGR2RGB)
        # Read image as grayscale
        mask = cv2.imread(self.maskPaths[idx], 0)
        ######mask = transforms.ToPILImage()(mask)

        image_store, mask_store = image_mask_transformation(image, mask, self.img_trans, self.aug_trans)
        return image_store, mask_store
```

Comment: Provide the full error back trace.

Comment: I have added the full error trace in my question as it was long

Comment: You are passing a batch of images to your transform operation while it expects single images (see [here](https://pytorch.org/vision/main/generated/torchvision.transforms.ToTensor.html)). Where is the transformation pipeline defined and called from?

Comment: I have added in my question from where I am calling the image- mask transformation